# Logspace containing specific points (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I can use `logspace(A,B,N)` to generate a vector of length `N`, containing points between `10^A` and `10^B` evenly spaced along a logarithmic axis. However, because of the nature of the logarithm, these points usually end up at data points which make no sense in themselves, and I have to create a logspace with a very large number of points if I want to make sure that a certain data point is exactly represented in the vector.

Is there a way for me to specify certain data points that should be included in the vector?

For example, `logspace(1,10,30, [25 50 75])` would generate a vector of lenght 30 with points distributed *almost* equally along a logarithmic axis, but making sure that all the points 25, 50 and 75 are included.

Comment: Why not just add the desired point(s), optionally eliding the nearest point(s) in the `logspace` output?

Comment: @reve_etrange: I'm currently adding them to the vector and then sorting the entire thing, but I thought it was ugly and went looking for something prettier =) In my case the sorting wasn't a performance problem - but it could have been, so I got curious on if I could be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are doing some sort of plot and what you need is the reference points for those specific values.  If that's the case you can also handle the logspace vector separately to the special values, for example, by overlaying two plots.

```
x = logspace(A, B, N);
y = f(x);                       % (whatever function or manipulation you want)

xSpecial = [25, 50, 75];
ySpecial = f(xSpecial);

plot(x, y);                     % plot function curve
hold on;
plot(xSpecial, ySpecial, 'ro'); % overlay special points with red circles
```

Otherwise I like @reve_etrange's idea of simply adding those specific points into your vector.

### Update

In a case like this where the calculations for each element do not depend on (1) the order of elements or (2) the values of the other elements in the vector, there is no need to sort the input for the purpose of calculation - and especially if you want to treat the special values differently when plotting.

Instead, just tack on the special values at the end, and then split the output vector to get the special outputs.

```
xRegular = logspace(A, B, N);        % N regular logspace values
xSpecial = [25, 50, 75];             % special particular values

xCombined = [xRegular, xSpecial];

yCombined = f(xCombined);            % whatever calculation you are doing

yRegular = yCombined(1:N);           % calculated values for xRegular
ySpecial = yCombined(N+1:end);       % calculated values for xSpecial

% e.g. plot with special points
plot(xRegular, yRegular);
hold on;
plot(xSpecial, ySpecial, 'ro');      % red circles indicate special points
```

Comment: In this case I was doing quite messy calculations on the logspace vector for something that I would eventually plot. However, I also needed to calculate values at specific points (i.e. not only plot them) and my main objective was to only perform the messy calculations once, on the vector with all the points.

Comment: Fair enough.  Although I think if the situation is as you describe the only potential problem is code duplication (rather than speed), which is fixed either by including the points in your vector or by putting all your messy calculations into a function.  If you're happy to plot the special points separately you don't even need to sort the initial logspace+specialpoints vector - just splice them off when you have the output vector.

Comment: That's actually a fantastic solution: if I just append the values to the end, and slice them off again when plotting, I don't have to sort or loop through the array at all, and I can still easily do everything just once! If you add that into your actual answer, I'll accept it =)

Comment: @Tomas done.  Not sure if I was clear enough in the explanation, but seems like you understand the suggestion anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Below I expand on the suggestion I made in a comment.  No sorting of `x` is necessary.

```
special_values;  %# vector of "special" points
x = logspace(A,B,N);
for i=1:length(special_values)
    [~,idx] = min(abs( x - special_values(i) ));
    x(idx) = special_values(i);
end
```

Problem with the above: the original values are elided.  I tried to just add the new values without any sorting at all, but I needed a second loop.  Assuming `special_values` is relatively small, it's OK though.

```
special_values = sort(special_values,'ascend');
x = logspace(A,B,N);
newx = zeros(1,length(x) + length(special_values));
lastx = 1;
lastnewx = 1;
for i=1:length(special_values)
    [~,idx] = min(abs( x - special_values(i) ));
    if special_values(i) == x(idx)
        continue;
    elseif special_values(i) > x(idx)
        newx(lastnewx:idx+i) = [x(lastx:idx) special_values(i)];
    else
        newx(lastnewx:idx+i) = [x(lastx:idx-1) special_values(i) x(idx)];
    end
    lastnewx = idx+i+1;
    lastx = idx+1;
end
if newx(end) == 0
    newx(lastnewx:end) = x(lastx:end);        
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but performance might be better if you use `zeros(...,1)`; and transpose `x`, `x = x';`, at the beginning, because MATLAB is column-major.  On the other hand, I've heard its better at dealing with this situation with respect to 1D arrays now.